# java writing to a text file using FreeMarker Templates

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

Need to write data  to a text file using Free Marker API, but when the line encounters 255 characters, the remaining characters should be printed to the next line .

Is this supported by Free Marker?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can pass whatever `java.io.Writer` to `Template.process` (or to `Environment.process`), you can pass one that writes to a file and inserts a CR when the line has reached 255 character. You will have to implement that `Writer` of course.